# Jquery blur event interfering with all other events

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form with multiple fields. I have jquery blur event handlers on all the fields that do some validation when you navigate away from a field. The problem is, if you are ever focused on a field, and then you click on any other link on the page, it validates the field but never allows the link to be clicked (or form be submitted).

```
$('.required').bind('blur', function(event) {
    validateAll($(event.target));
});

function validateAll(elm) {
   //blah blah
   return false;
}
```

The validateAll function just does a check and returns false after.

Basically, when a user is focused on a field, they must click any button twice in order for it to work. The first one activates the blur validation, and then second one actually clicks through the link.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few other posts similar to this.

The common solution is to try adding a delay in your blur event handler, like so:

```
$('.required').bind('blur', function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() 
    { 
        validateAll($(event.target)); 
    }, 10);
});
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

You're not returning validateAll in your blur handler, although you said it "just does a check and returns false after".  If it's returning false to try and prevent further event bubbling, you'd want to return that rather than just calling validateAll (and doing nothing with what it returns).

Don't see how any of that would cause the problem you're describing, but maybe I'm just misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: I added some code to show how it returns. What I meant was that regardless of what goes inside of the validateAll in the end, that function always returns false. But I agree, I don't know why that could prevent other event handlers from being called.

Comment: I think you're missing my point: it's not about what validateAll returns, it's about what the blur event handler returns.  validateAll returning false does NOTHING by itself: that function can return false until the cows come home, and unless you return what it returns inside the blur handler, the validateAll return statement will be meaningless.